# Tkinter embedded graph changing plot axes

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter, graph

So I here I have a basic GUI that includes 2 frames. The first page has two drop-down menus, where the user can select columns from the dataframe. It also includes a button which, when pressed, outputs both both selected columns onto labels (this is just to make sure that it is selecting correctly).

What I have tried to get the code to do, is make it so that the graph updates with a new plot each time a new column is selected on the drop down menu. I assumed it would be as simple as assigning these to a string variable but this doesn't seem to work.

There is a second page also with a graph in case it is easier to have this functionality across frames but ideally it would be kept on the same one.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        [10, 11, 12]],
        columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

xList = []
yList = []

Options = df.dtypes.index 

fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "GUI")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Home, Graph):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Home)




    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        def selectXY():
            x = varX.get()            
            y = varY.get()

            ax.clear() 


            X.config(text=x)
            Y.config(text=y)

            xList = df.loc[:,X]
            yList = df.loc[:,Y]


            return xList
            return yList

        #Y axis select
        varY = tk.StringVar(self)
        # initial value
        varY.set('Select Y axis')

        optionY = tk.OptionMenu(self, varY, *Options)

        optionY.pack()

        #X axis select
        varX = tk.StringVar(self)
        # initial value
        varX.set('Select X axis')

        optionX = tk.OptionMenu(self, varX, *Options)

        optionX.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Plot Axes", command = selectXY)

        button2.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Graph))
        button2.pack()

        Y = ttk.Label(self, text=yList)
        Y.pack()

        X = ttk.Label(self, text=xList)
        X.pack()


        df.plot.scatter(xList, yList, ax=ax)


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)



class Graph(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        df.plot.scatter(xList, yList, ax=ax)


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
        button3.pack()

app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following adjustments:

1. Move your figure build into the *selectXY* method so button can run it on click.
2. Pass axes by name into [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) which takes *x* and *y* as string values. Hence, *xList* and *yList* with `.loc` calls are not needed and values can derive directly out of *varX* and *varY* drop downs.
3. Finally, move canvas to the `__init__` method to be called once and not create a new canvas each time.

Below is adjustment of *Home* class:

```
class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

        def selectXY():
            x = varX.get()            
            y = varY.get()

            X.config(text=x)
            Y.config(text=y)

            ax.clear()
            df.plot.scatter(x, y, ax=ax)

            canvas.draw()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Y axis select
        varY = tk.StringVar(self)
        # initial value
        varY.set('Select Y axis')

        optionY = tk.OptionMenu(self, varY, *Options)
        optionY.pack()

        # X axis select
        varX = tk.StringVar(self)
        # initial value
        varX.set('Select X axis')

        optionX = tk.OptionMenu(self, varX, *Options)
        optionX.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Plot Axes", command = selectXY)
        button2.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Graph))
        button2.pack()

        Y = ttk.Label(self, text=yList)
        Y.pack()

        X = ttk.Label(self, text=xList)
        X.pack()
```

For *Graph* class to replicate same plot as *Home* requires some extensive adjustment with global variables, visiblity trigger event in *show_frame*, and updated attributes in *Graph*.